# What is the best way to delete all pages in Sitefinity via code?

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I was wondering what is the best way to delete all pages in Sitefinity?
I came up with two solutions but I'm not sure what the best practices are.
I also read the [documentation](https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-delete-pages) fore deleting pages.
The goal is to delete hierarchical pages as well.

**Fluent**

```
 var fluent = App.WorkWith().Pages(); 
 fluent.LocatedIn(Telerik.Sitefinity.Fluent.Pages.PageLocation.Frontend).Delete().SaveChanges();
```

**Native**

```
var pageManager = PageManager.GetManager();
var pageNodes = pageManager.GetPageNodes().ToList();
foreach (var node in pageNodes)
{
   pageManager.DeleteItem(node);
}

pageManager.SaveChanges();
```

P.S. I was using the **Fluent** approach but after a while an error started to pop up. I switched to **PageManager** approach but I get the same error. I deleted all pages from the backend and the recycle bin, but still no resolution.

> No row for Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.PageNode ('sf_page_node')
>   GenericOID@4f0f7ba8 PageNode id=6bd454ba-6971-4289-822d-36fbd9f5a844
>   NOTRES

*Edit:* The pages are deleted despite the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be very specific when deleting pages as the native version you are using will pull all pages including BackendPages. I have deleted **ALL** the pages in a Sitefinity site before.

According to the docs they use a slightly different approach for deleting pages.

https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-delete-pages#delete-a-page-using-native-api

This deletes by title but can be easily modified to suit you. The docs also recommend unpublishing the page before deletion too.

```
public void DeletePageNativeAPI(string pageTitleToDelete)
        {
            PageManager pageManager = PageManager.GetManager();
            PageData page = pageManager.GetPageDataList().Where(pD => (pD.NavigationNode.Title == pageTitleToDelete && pD.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (page != null)
            {
                pageManager.Delete(page);
                pageManager.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Pages consist of a Template > PageNode > PageData
https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-crud-operations-with-pages#page-components

Depending of which version you are working with of Sitefinity pages are a little different since the addition of Personalization and such.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really matter which way you go (Fluent vs Native) - the end result should be the same. It is just a matter of coding style and readability.

I like Native more because I feel I have more control :)

As for the error - when using the PageManager - have you tried

pageManager.Delete(node) as opposed to the pageManager.DeleteItem(node)?

They seem slightly different.

How many pages do you have to delete?

If they are thousands, you can add a counter and call pageManager.SaveChanges() on every 100 or so deletions so that the transaction is committed to the DB.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `pageManager.Delete(node)` but I still get the same error. **I forgot to mention that the pages are deleted successfully**. Despite the error.
I am using similar approach for deleting all news items, the items are deleted and there is no error. My guess is that I'm missing out something specific for pages. 
Also the pages are not more than 10.

Comment: Does the error occur after deleting a particular page node or is it at random every time?

Comment: It happens at every method call. But it appears that I messed up something with my db at some point, because the _PageNode Id_ shown in the error is the same every time.